# Стоит ли в данном случае разделять приложение на "микросервисы"? Удачно ли спроектировано приложение?

Tags: архитектура, проектирование

Поставлена цель написать Telegram-бота, который следит за сабреддитами и при появлении новых постов отправляет им в чаты, которые подписаны на эти сабреддиты. Бот написан, всё работает в одном месте - как только появляет пост на сабреддите, бот сразу же отправляет шлёт сообщение в чаты. Мне захотелось разделить эти две части, потому что кол-во пользователей может расти, следовательно одного аккаунта (на реддит) может не хватить, чтобы получать абсолютно все посты. Я разделил бота и функции, отвечающие за отслеживанием новых постов, но появился вопрос - а как этим двум общаться между собой?
(Изначально приложение было написано на Python, так что при старте я создавал задачу, которая будет выполняться в event loop (`asyncio.create_task`))

Первое, что приходит на ум, - база данных. Причём в БД надо только писать, обновлять информацию о постах не надо, а через n дней информация о постах уже не нужна, так как всё уже есть в Telegram. Но уместно ли так делать?

Comment: может лучше не БД, а просто шина сообщений? RabbitMQ, например